# Entity Framework Core + Count with Group By

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table which contains ~600k records and 33 columns. In my project I am using EF Core (2.0.1) to retrieve data from database. I am having issues with below code:

```
 var theCounter = (from f in _context.tblData.Take(100000)
         group f by f.TypeId into data
         select new DataDto { ID = data.Key, Count = data.Count() }).ToList();
```

This code is a part of REST API and when I am testing it from SOAP UI, I am gettin timeout error. When I tested the code for

> Take(1000)

There are around 300 unique TypeIds.
it works fine. Any ideas how I can make it work?

-- EDIT 1:

Here is what I see when debugging the code:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: Query: '(from TblData <generated>_1 in DbSet<TblData> select [<generated>_1]).Take(__p_0)' uses a row limiting operation (Skip/Take) without OrderBy which may lead to unpredictable results.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: Query: '(from TblData <generated>_1 in DbSet<TblData> select [<generated>_1]).Take(__p_0)' uses a row limiting operation (Skip/Take) without OrderBy which may lead to unpredictable results.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([f].TypeId, [f])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([f].TypeId, [f])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (131ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [t2].[Id], [t2].[at], [t2].[add], [t2].[AddDate], [t2].[aftc], [t2].[aftcd], [t2].[aid], [t2].[afl], [t2].[prdid], [t2].[cid], [t2].[TypeId], [t2].[env], [t2].[ext], [t2].[extddcode], [t2].[fn], [t2].[fn], [t2].[fic], [t2].[gid], [t2].[grp], [t2].[hnm], [t2].[IP], [t2].[icid], [t2].[ln], [t2].[lg], [t2].[pcid], [t2].[ret], [t2].[rts], [t2].[rnam], [t2].[sled], [t2].[seq], [t2].[sid], [t2].[styp]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t1].[Id], [t1].[at], [t1].[add], [t1].[AddDate], [t1].[aftc], [t1].[aftcd], [t1].[aid], [t1].[afl], [t1].[prdid], [t1].[cid], [t1].[TypeId], [t1].[env], [t1].[ext], [t1].[extddcode], [t1].[fn], [t1].[fn], [t1].[fic], [t1].[gid], [t1].[grp], [t1].[hnm], [t1].[IP], [t1].[icid], [t1].[ln], [t1].[lg], [t1].[pcid], [t1].[ret], [t1].[rts], [t1].[rnam], [t1].[sled], [t1].[seq], [t1].[sid], [t1].[styp]
    FROM [TblData] AS [t1]
) AS [t2]
WHERE [t2].[TypeId] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [t2].[TypeId]
```

I think it is not translated properly. Any ideas why?

-- EDIT 2:

I have changed my queries to:

```
    var query = _context.TblData
        .Select(a => new {ID = a.Id, TypeId= a.TypeId})
        .Distinct();

    var q1 = query.GroupBy(p => p.TypeId)
        .Select(g => new DataDto {TypeId= g.Key, Count = g.Count()});

    return await q1.ToListAsync();
```

But it was translated to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [a0].[Id], [a0].[TypeId] AS [TypeId]
FROM [tblData] AS [a0]
ORDER BY [a0].[TypeId]
```

When I checked directly in the database this query takes 14 seconds to execute. Any idea why it was not translated to something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [a0].[Id], COUNT([TypeId]) AS [TypeId]
FROM [tblData] AS [a0]
GROUP BY COUNT([a0].[Id])
ORDER BY [a0].[TypeId]
```

Comment: Are you displaying your records? You can use pagination and use Skip and Take in your query

Comment: No, I am not displaying it. I just want to get the counts to use it somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Can you see the query that EF constructs?

Comment: What EF Core version are you on?

Comment: @IvanStoev I am using 2.0.1. I've updated my post.

Comment: Consider upgrading to 2.1 in order to get [GroupBy translation improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation)

Comment: @IvanStoev - Yes I was in the middle of upgrade to version 2.1 when I sent you my current version :) After upgrade to 2.1 the query is translated properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade EF Core version to 2.1 and LINQ is now translated properly into SQL.